# foward fill data frame based on location of "1"s from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    prac = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
     "B": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     "DesiredResult": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]}
)

newDf = prac[['A','B']].mask(prac==0)
newDf['buySell'] =  newDf['A'].combine_first(newDf['B'])
newDf['buySell'].ffill(inplace=True)
newDf
```

this is what I have done/written so far:

1. I utilized **mask()** and create **"NaN"** values of **columns "A" and "B"**
2. next, I combined **column "A" and "B"** into a single column.
3. This is the part where I'm having trouble as I am trying to use **ffill()** to based on the range of the **1's** in both columns.

Not sure how to deal w/ the **ffill()**  based on the 2 columns from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a reverse `cummax` (or `bfill` if you have NaNs in place of 0) per group based on A:

```
prac['buySell'] = (prac.loc[::-1, 'B']
                   .groupby(prac['A'].eq(1).cumsum())
                   .cummax()[::-1]
                  )
```

Output:

```
    A  B  DesiredResult  buySell
0   0  0              0        0
1   1  0              1        1
2   0  0              1        1
3   0  1              1        1
4   0  1              1        1
5   0  1              1        1
6   0  0              0        0
7   1  0              1        1
8   0  0              1        1
9   0  0              1        1
10  0  0              1        1
11  0  0              1        1
12  0  1              1        1
13  0  1              1        1
14  0  1              1        1
15  0  0              0        0
```

Alternative:

```
newDf = prac[['A','B']].mask(prac==0)
         
newDf['buySell'] = newDf['B'].groupby(newDf['A'].eq(1).cumsum()).bfill()
```

Output:

```
      A    B  buySell
0   NaN  NaN      NaN
1   1.0  NaN      1.0
2   NaN  NaN      1.0
3   NaN  1.0      1.0
4   NaN  1.0      1.0
5   NaN  1.0      1.0
6   NaN  NaN      NaN
7   1.0  NaN      1.0
8   NaN  NaN      1.0
9   NaN  NaN      1.0
10  NaN  NaN      1.0
11  NaN  NaN      1.0
12  NaN  1.0      1.0
13  NaN  1.0      1.0
14  NaN  1.0      1.0
15  NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Comment: mozway,

thank you very much for your alternative answer.  this was exactly what I was looking for.  After utilizing rhug123's answer, I realize that backFilling would be the better approach.  Greatly Apprecaited!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = prac['A'].eq(1)
e = prac['B'].eq(1)

s.where(s|(e.diff(-1).ne(0) & e).shift()).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    1
15    0
```

Comment: rhug123,

I think this should work.  Will try this out later on my actual dataset.  just out of curiosoity,  just started a month ago, I was wondering what does "|" mean?  in regards to where(s|(e.diff(-1).

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

"The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not."

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification.  It was sort of what I thought that was.